# Sentence Similarity using WS4J

Tags: java, nlp, wordnet, jaws-wordnet, ws4j

I want to use ws4j to calculate similarity between two sentence.
I am using the Online Demo of WS4J @ [WS4J Online demo](http://ws4jdemo.appspot.com/<br/)

I am using the default example sentences given by WS4J. 
After entering the sentence and hitting on calculate similarity button, i am getting the following output:[image]

Here i am getting the similarity between individual tokens of the sentence.
How do i proceed further from here.I want to get a single value (say 0.5 or 0.8) which denotes the similarity of these 2 sentences.
Is there a standard way of proceeding from here or will i have to write my own algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

> will i have to write my own algorithm?

Yes. Check this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300485/how-to-resolve-the-difference-between-the-values-attained-in-the-web-api-and-the) out.