# How to resolve the difference between the values attained in the Web API and the ones attained through the source in ws4j?

Tags: java, nlp, matching, ws4j

I developed the following API for semantic matching for sentences using ws4j library. But im failing to get the semantic similarities. 
The ouptut is attached as an image which shows values which are redundant or 0. 
Is there any library which is missed out to be called?

```
package ws4jv01;

import edu.cmu.lti.lexical_db.ILexicalDatabase;
import edu.cmu.lti.lexical_db.NictWordNet;
import edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.RelatednessCalculator;
import edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.HirstStOnge;
import edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.JiangConrath;
import edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.LeacockChodorow;
import edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.Lesk;
import edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.Lin;
import edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.Path;
import edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.Resnik;
import edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.WuPalmer;

public class SentenceMatcherSimilarityMatrix
{
 private static ILexicalDatabase db = new NictWordNet();
 public double[][] getSimilarityMatrix( String[] words1, String[] words2, RelatednessCalculator rc )
{
    double[][] result = new double[words1.length][words2.length];
    for ( int i=0; i<words1.length; i++ ){
        for ( int j=0; j<words2.length; j++ ) {
            double score = rc.calcRelatednessOfWords(words1[i], words2[j]);
            result[i][j] = score;
          }
        }
    return result;
  }
  private void compute (String[] words1, String[] words2)
  {
    System.out.println("WuPalmer");
    RelatednessCalculator rc1 = new WuPalmer(db);
       {
        double[][] s1 = getSimilarityMatrix(words1, words2,rc1);
        for(int i=0; i<words1.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j< words2.length; j++){
                System.out.print(s1[i][j] +"\t");
            } 
            System.out.println();
        }}
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Resnik");
    RelatednessCalculator rc2 = new Resnik(db);
    {
        double[][] s2 = getSimilarityMatrix(words1, words2,rc2);
        for(int i=0; i<words1.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j< words2.length; j++){
                System.out.print(s2[i][j] +"\t");
            } 
            System.out.println();
        }}
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("JiangConrath");
    RelatednessCalculator rc3 = new JiangConrath(db);
    {
        double[][] s2 = getSimilarityMatrix(words1, words2,rc3);
        for(int i=0; i<words1.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j< words2.length; j++){
                System.out.print(s2[i][j] +"\t");
            } 
            System.out.println();
        }}
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Lin");
    RelatednessCalculator rc4 = new Lin(db);
    {
        double[][] s2 = getSimilarityMatrix(words1, words2,rc4);
        for(int i=0; i<words1.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j< words2.length; j++){
                System.out.print(s2[i][j] +"\t");
            } 
            System.out.println();
        }}
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("LeacockChodrow");
    RelatednessCalculator rc5 = new LeacockChodorow(db);
    {
        double[][] s2 = getSimilarityMatrix(words1, words2,rc5);
        for(int i=0; i<words1.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j< words2.length; j++){
                System.out.print(s2[i][j] +"\t");
            } 
            System.out.println();
        }}
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Path");
    RelatednessCalculator rc6 = new Path(db);
    {
        double[][] s2 = getSimilarityMatrix(words1, words2,rc6);
        for(int i=0; i<words1.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j< words2.length; j++){
                System.out.print(s2[i][j] +"\t");
            } 
            System.out.println();
        }}
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Lesk");
    RelatednessCalculator rc7 = new Lesk(db);
    {
        double[][] s2 = getSimilarityMatrix(words1, words2,rc7);
        for(int i=0; i<words1.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j< words2.length; j++){
                System.out.print(s2[i][j] +"\t");
            } 
            System.out.println();
        }}
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("HirstStOnge");
    RelatednessCalculator rc8 = new HirstStOnge(db);
    {
        double[][] s2 = getSimilarityMatrix(words1, words2,rc8);

        for(int i=0; i<words1.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j< words2.length; j++){
                System.out.print(s2[i][j] +"\t");
            } 
            System.out.println();
           }}
          }

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String sent1 = "The boy is playing with a dog.";
    String sent2 = "The kid is playing with his pet.";

    String[] words1 = sent1.split(" ");
    String[] words2 = sent2.split(" ");
    SentenceMatcherSimilarityMatrix sm1 = new SentenceMatcherSimilarityMatrix(); 
    sm1.compute(words1, words2);
}
}
```

[Result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sRBA.png)

Comment: Your code appears to be working. The really large redundant values correspond to identical words that occur in both sentences, and the zeroes occur because all but two of the similarity measures will only compare words that share the same part of speech.

Comment: Will this work on JAVA8?

Answer (score 0):

Minor optimization in rendering of similarity matrix:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= words1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= words2.length; j++) {
        if(i==0 && j==0) {
            System.out.print(" " + "\t"); 
        } else if(i==0) {
            System.out.print(words2[j-1] + "\t");
        } else if(j==0) {
            System.out.print(words1[i-1] + "\t");
        } else {
            System.out.print(s1[i-1][j-1] + "\t");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This will render the matrix as:
[image]